# Convergence Of Improper Integrals With Different Limits

Tags: calculus

Prove that if the integral $$\int_a^xf(t)dt$$ converges then the integral $$\int_b^xf(t)dt$$ also converges for any real number $b$ provided the integral $\int_a^xf(t)dt$exits for every $x$.
$$$$Given that the integral $$\int_a^xf(t)dt$$ converges. Now suppose $b>a$ then we have $$\int_a^xf(t)dt=\int_a^bf(t)dt+\int_b^xf(t)dt$$. Now as $\int_a^xf(t)dt$ converges and $\int_a^bf(t)dt$ is a constant, so $\int_b^xf(t)dt$ must also converge. Similarly we can prove the case when $b<a$.
$$$$Is My Proof Correct?

Comment: The equality you wrote is not correct.

Comment: But why the equality is not correct?

Comment: It implies that $\int_a^b f(t)dt = 0$.

Comment: Oh sorry! by mistake I wrote $a$ in place of $b$

Comment: Now is the proof Correct?

Comment: Hey what happened ??